# Integer values in leveldb

Tags: c++, python, integer, leveldb

I would like to use leveldb to store integers and integer arrays efficiently, in both c++ and python.

For integers in C++, i could convert the int to a char array. Any suggestions for storing the int array in c++ and int and int array in python?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using a library like Google's protobuf (http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) which is capable of (de)serializing structured data. For the case you mention, a repeated field would do the trick:

```
message List {
  repeated int64 val = 1;
}
```

Given the varint encoding used by protocol buffers (and depending on your range of values) this could be an efficient way to store the integers.

http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/encoding.html#varints

It is tough to say more without knowing a bit more about your use case. How many integers are going to be stored per array on average? What is the range of integer values? etc.

Answer (score 0):

For an `int` array in c++ you have to pass the `int` array as a `char*` to the Slice class, which you can then easily put to the leveldb database, e.g.

```
int myArray[3] = {1,2,3};
Slice valueSlice = Slice( (const char*) myArray, sizeof(myArray) );
```

This is basically valid for all types as well as custom classes, e.g.

```
MyClass* newObj = new MyClass();
Slice valueSlice = Slice( (const char*) newObj, sizeof(MyClass) );
```

Answer (score 0):

for python, [struct](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) can be efficient. Here is an example using the ctypes leveldb interface from [leveldb-py](http://code.google.com/p/leveldb-py/) storing the value 1,2,3,4,5 (as an array of integers) in the database with key 100:

```
import leveldb,array,struct

#this assumes 32-bit unsigned integers in machine order
value=struct.pack('p',array('I',[1,2,3,4,5]))
key=struct.pack('I',100)

db=leveldb.DB("/path/to/db", create_if_missing=True)
db[key]=value
```

For more efficiency, import the specific functions (e.g. "from struct import pack") and use the lelveldb's WriteBatch class, if you have a bunch of writes to do.

[Can integer keys / values be stored in LevelDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804834/can-integer-keys-values-be-stored-in-leveldb) suggests that a custom comparator may be needed, however this particular Python leveldb interface doesn't support that.  https://plyvel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ may be a better option.

Comment: If you are just using leveldb as a key-value store, you don't need a custom comparator.