# LevelDB: Iterate keys by insertion order

Tags: leveldb

What's a good strategy for generating auto-incrementing keys in LevelDB?  My goal is to be able to iterate over the keys in the order that they were inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a LevelDB instance can only be accessed from one application at a time, you might as well use a 64-bit long and increment it in the application. When opening the DB (and before allowing any writes), to find the last inserted key you can use the SeekToLast() method of the Iterator.

Answer (score 3):

two methods:

1. use the default comparator, but use a function to convert the index key '1' to something like '000000001', convert '20' to '000000020', so leveldb will place them near each other;
2. self define a new comparator, which convert the key from type string to type integer, then you can compare the integer.

with any of the above 2 methods, you need to store a key-value pair in the leveldb:  current_id ----> integer, or you can store the current id in a new file using mmap.

then, with yourself defined Add() function, after you get the current id from key current_id you can insert a new key-value pair:  id ----> value,   then you can update the current_id to plus one.

Answer (score 1):

As I just pointed out in a [question on integer keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804834/can-integer-keys-values-be-stored-in-leveldb), if you want to use binary integers you need to create a custom Comparator for the database, otherwise you don't get them in ascending binary order. It's not hard but you may have overlooked the need.

I'm not quite sure what you're asking. If the only data you are adding is keys which are supposed to record an entry as a log then yes, just use an integer key.

However, if you are inserting keys you are going to search for some other reason PLUS you want to later iterate them in insertion order, it gets a bit more complex.

Basically you want to insert two keys for each key value, using a prefix to determine whether keys are "value keys" or "ordering keys". e.g., say you have Frank, John, Sally and Amy as keys and use prefix ~N for Name keys and ~I for Iterator keys.

The database looks like the following, note that the "Iterator keys" don't have a value associated with them as we can just get the names out of the key. I've shown it as if you used a string of two digits for the number, rather than using an integer value and needing a special Comparator.

```
~I00Frank
~I01John
~I02Sally
~I03Amy
~NAmy => Amy's details
~NFrank => frank's details 
~NJohn => John's details
~NSally => Sally's details
```